# How to save a query result into a csv file without using pandas inside python?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to save the results of a query into a csv file(employee_file.csv) in the current directory using below code but when i open the csv, there is no data in there. I'm getting **<tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper object at 0x0000020D68A704C0>**

```
def read_sql_tmpfile(query, conn):
    print("Query started, be patient")
    logging.info('Retrieving data from xpress table started at ' + datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y/%m/%d/%H-%M-%S'))
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
        copy_sql = "COPY ({query}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV {head}".format(
            query=query, head="HEADER"
        )
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.copy_expert(copy_sql, tmpfile)
        tmpfile.seek(0)
        with open('employee_file.csv', mode='w') as employee_file:
            employee_writer = csv.writer(tmpfile, delimiter=',')
```

My way seem not to work. How would i go about fixing this?

Comment: Do you actually use employee_writer for anything? And shouldn't it write to employee_file, not to tmpfile?

Comment: I need to use that csv file somwhere.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to convert some database data to .csv format. It is pretty straightforward. You have to first make a connection with a database then create a cursor instance, send query through that cursor instance, fetch your data into a data frame & close the connection. Then you can write that data frame to a csv file.

Following is a snippet from one of my codes:

For e.g.

```
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

conn=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd=xxxxxx',db='world')

c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("select CountryCode from countrylanguage where IsOfficial='T' and Language= 'English';")
all_rows=c.fetchall()
conn.close()
df=pd.DataFrame(list(all_rows),columns=["Official_Language_English"])
df.to_csv("random_file_name.csv")
```

Comment: The problem is, I'm trying to avoid using pandas. Any other way of doing that without using pandas?

Comment: Hmm, seems difficult but I'll try and let you know if I get something sensible.